# Count filled input boxes

Tags: php, html

```
<input type="number" name="day1">
<input type="number" name="day2">
<input type="number" name="day3>
```

My question is, how to count only filled fields, so if I fill only `day1` with some value, count result will be 1, and if I fill 3 days with some values, count result will be 3.

I'm using php + html.

Comment: Do you have a form? Or what?

Comment: I think you will have to use JavaScript and an IF statement to see if the value of the textboxes is null or not

Comment: Yes, i have a form and everything is working fine (about form), but i need that "count" function.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: I took a look on php.net but i don't see tutorial how to count only filled fields. There is just example to count all or just selected.

Comment: `Print_r($_POST)` and see what is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use an array of inputs instead of numbered names:

```
<input type="number" name="day[1]">
<input type="number" name="day[2]">
<input type="number" name="day[3]">
```

Then in PHP just filter out empty ones:

```
$count = count(array_filter($_POST['day']));
```

That will filter out `0` as well, if you don't want that then filter checking for an empty string:

```
$count = count(array_filter($_POST['day'], function($v) { return $v !== '';}));
```